# fast-xml-parser incorrect parse array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a problem with the parser incorrectly converting the array.

Array creation code (Look at DocFiles):

```
documents.push({
  // Document fields...
  DocFiles: []
});

for (const file of files) {
  documents[documents.length - 1].DocFiles.push({ File: file });
}
```

Or:

```
documents.push({
  // Document fields...
  DocFiles: files.map(file => ({ File: file }))
});
```

The array gets the following form:

```
documents: [
  {
    DocFiles: [
      { File: Object },
      { File: Object },
      { File: Object }
  },
  {
    DocFiles: [
      { File: Object },
      { File: Object },
      { File: Object }
  }
]
```

What I want to get in each document in the DocFiles node:

```
<DocFiles>
    <File>{fileNodes}</File>
    <File>{fileNodes}</File>
    <File>{fileNodes}</File>
</DocFiles>
```

What I get:

```
<DocFiles>
    <File>{fileNodes}</File>
</DocFiles>
<DocFiles>
    <File>{fileNodes}</File>
</DocFiles>
<DocFiles>
    <File>{fileNodes}</File>
</DocFiles>
```

What am I doing wrong?

- Parser options:

```
const options = {
  attributeNamePrefix: '@_',
  attrNodeName: '@',
  textNodeName: '#text',
  ignoreAttributes: true,
  cdataTagName: '__cdata',
  cdataPositionChar: '\\c',
  format: true,
  indentBy: '    ',
  supressEmptyNode: true,
  tagValueProcessor: a => a,
  attrValueProcessor: a => a
}
```

- Parsing and writing code:

```
for (const document of documents) {
  const parent = { Nomenclature: document };
  const fileName = `${Date.now().toString()}.xml`;
  const Parser = xml.j2xParser;
  const parser = new Parser(options);
  const value = await parser.parse(parent);

  await fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dir, fileName), value);
}
```

- Before parsing:

[image]

- Parsing result:

[image]

Comment: You should copy paste your code here instead of using images. It will stay there even if the images are down, and we won't have to click to open them...

Comment: ok i changed the question

Comment: @SergeySovgut You can accept an answer if your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
documents.push({
  // Document fields...
  DocFiles: files.map(file => ({ File: file }))
});
```

In this example, you push in a new object with DockFiles property. An array in this object.

Maybe you will try this, your issue will be fixed.

```
documents['DocFiles'] = files.map(file => ({ File: file }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this solution does not work, since the documents are an array, and in each cell of this array there is a DocFiles property, which is also an array, and I need to already place files in it

Answer (score 2):

I found an solution...

```
documents.push({
  // Document fields...
  DocFiles: {
    DocFile: files.map(file => file)
  }
});
```

Thanks for helping :)